# Get the length of decimal places

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel sheet where I have several columns and one column is `Amount` where I've to validate each cell and check whether it's length after decimal point is greater than 2 and if yes then throw error.

```
Public Function CheckLength(value As String) As Integer
    Dim n As Double
    Dim itg As Integer
    Dim dcm As Double
    n = value 'Say Value is 50.01 here 
    itg = Int(n) 'Will be 50
    dcm = Split(n - itg, ".")(1) 'But n-itg will yield something and dcm`s value will be 
    '1000001 some strange value where as it has to be `01` or say whatever comes after decimal part
    CheckLength = Len(dcm)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
Public Function CheckLength(value As String) As Integer
    Dim n As Double
    Dim itg As Integer
    Dim dcm As Double
    n = value
    itg = Int(n)
    dcm = Len(CStr(n)) - InStr(CStr(n), ".")

    CheckLength = dcm
End Function
```

Note: if there is no `"."` in n, it will return the total length (because it will be `Len(CStr(n)) - 0`) so you could check if the string contains a `"."` before, or you can check if `dcm` is the same as `Len(CStr(n))` and then return `0`.

Comment: `num`? I hope it should be `n`?

Comment: No issues buddy!! Let me give a try! and then I think I don't need `itg` here right?

Comment: Beauty!! Perfect!! Accepting in next 4 minutes!! Banged my head whole day with this.. :) Are there any cons for this approach? I mean will it ignore any sort of values as of your knowledge!!

Comment: Thanks alot bro.. :) Please add your comments in the answer as it will be very useful!! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're actually checking numbers then this will work:

```
Function CheckLength(value As Double) As Integer
    If InStr(CStr(value), ".") Then
        CheckLength = Len(Split(CStr(value), ".")(1))
    Else
       CheckLength = 0
    End If
End Function
```

---

It converts the number to a string, splits it using `"."` as the delimiter and then returns the length of the second item in the array returned (which is anything after the `"."`)

```
Const myNumber As Double = 50.13245
Debug.Print CheckLength(myNumber) '// Returns 5

'// Split 50.13245 on "." returns an array with 2 parts:
'//    (0) = "50"
'//    (1) = "13245"
'//    Length of (1) '13245' = 5
```

Comment: Your update works well!! Thank you for your time.. :)